# How do I perform a login to a website correctly? 403 Forbidden error

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

So, I just got in to HttpWebRequest & response and I managed to login to a very basic website.
Now, I am currently trying to do the same thing but to a "more advanced" website.
I've used fiddler to get a hold of the URL & the headers but for some reason I am still getting a Forbidden 403 error. I've tried logging in with a valid username & password as well as non valid ones just to see the difference, and there was none.
I would need help with understanding WHY I am getting this error.
I was reading online about what could cause this and all I could find was that I needed to set the headers which I did. I think I got them all at least.

There is a small issue as well which is the csrf token thing. and that's really not an issue since you can just perform an empty login and get a token generated for you and use it over and over again.
Anyways.. I have no idea why I am getting the 403 ERROR.

The website I'm trying to login to is https://bokon.se

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get the post params & convert them correctly.
            string useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36";

            string postData = $"csrfmiddlewaretoken=kwQfWirQCDU3Xfr4fm1i8AmEJmr15JlK&username={tbPassword.Text}&password={tbUsername.Text}&login_form=Logga+in";
            byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

            //Create the request to the server
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://bokon.se/konto/login/?next=");
            //httpWebRequest.Headers["Content-Type:"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            httpWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            httpWebRequest.Headers["Referrer"] = "https://bokon.se/konto/login/?next=";
            httpWebRequest.UserAgent = useragent;
            httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;

            using (Stream stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            }
//This is where the error occurs.
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
            using (var streamreader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
                Debug.Print(result);
            }
            //tsLabel.Text = "Success.";
        }
```

Comment: have you tried removing the csrf token from both sides?

Comment: You mean in the code?

Comment: yes. in the code. try to remove part by part till you find where the error is coming from